# how to print all match using grep

Tags: grep

I have a txt file that has only information about location (location.txt)
Another large txt file (all.txt) has a lot of information like id , and a location.txt is subset of all.txt ( some records common in both )
I want to search the location.txt in another file with grep (all.txt)
and print all common records ( but all information like all.txt )
I try to grep by :

```
grep -f location.txt all.txt
```

the problem grep just give me the last location not all locations
how can I print all location?

Comment: It would be better if you can share the location.txt, all.txt, and the expected output.

Comment: location.txt

1452737
1674993


all.txt
A            ......       1452737
B            .......      1973738
C            .......       1674993
D            ......        9293773


the output must be like this
A            ......       1452737
C            .......       1674993

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean to use one of the files as a set of patterns for `grep`. If this is the case, you seem to be looking for a way to print all lines in one file not found in the other and this is what you want:

```
grep -vFf file_with_patterns other_file
```

Explanation

`-F` means to interpret the pattern(s) literally, giving no particular meaning to regex metacharacters (like `*` and `+`, for example)

`-f` means read regex patterns from the file named as argument (`file_with_patterns` in this case).

Comment: One way with awk:

`awk -v FS="[ =]" 'NR==FNR{rows[$1]++;next}(substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1) in rows)' File1 File2`